# Trouble passing a $Component

Tags: visualforce-component, id, parameters

I have a small problem sending an Id through a $Component. Thanks everybody!

```
<apex:page standardController="Entrada__c" extensions="BA_vista_item_entrada">

<style>
.ct{text-align:right;}
</style>

<apex:form id="formItems">

    <apex:pageBlock id="pageblockItems">

    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>

    <apex:outputpanel id="panelItemsEntrada" style="overflow:scroll;height:370px;" layout="block">
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="TablaItems" value="{!dataRecords}" var="p" styleclass="fixme"> 

            <apex:column headerValue="Acción" width="10%" rendered="{!!entrada.Cerrada__c}">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Eliminar" action="{!deleteItem}" reRender="TablaItems" status="loadingStatus" style="color:#015ba7;" onclick="if(!confirm('Seguro que desea eliminar el item seleccionado?')){return};">
                        <apex:param value="{!p.id}" name="ItemBorrado" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>                

            <apex:column headerValue="Etiqueta" style="text-align:left;" width="10%" >
                <apex:commandButton value="Generar Etiqueta" onclick="window.open('/apex/BA_generarEtiquetaEntrada?id={!p.id}','Popup','height=600,width=1200,left=100,top=50,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');"/>
            </apex:column>

             <apex:column headervalue="Producto Entrada" width="30%">
                 <apex:inputField id="producto" value="{!p.ProductoEntrada__c}" style="width: 90%; " styleClass="display:none;" rendered="true" onchange="check()"/>
              </apex:column>

            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%" headerClass="ct" id="columnItem">
                <apex:facet name="header">Espacio Almacén</apex:facet>
                <apex:commandButton value="Asignar espacio" onclick="window.open('/apex/BA_StockVisual_Entradas?id={!$Component.formItems.pageblockItems.panelItemsEntrada.TablaItems.columnItem.espacioAlmacen}&al={!entrada.Almacen__c}','Popup','height=600,width=400,left=4500,top=750,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');"/>
                <apex:outputText id="espacioAlmacen">A1A1</apex:outputText>
            </apex:column> 


            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%" headerClass="ct">
                <apex:facet name="header">Estiba</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.Uds_Estiba__c}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>                

            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%" headerClass="ct">
                <apex:facet name="header">Peso Caja</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.Peso_Caja__c}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>    

            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%" headerClass="ct">
                <apex:facet name="header">Número Cajas</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.N_mero_Cajas__c}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>                

            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%" headerClass="ct">
                <apex:facet name="header">Candidad de Kilos</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.Peso_Kg__c}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}" />
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>            

            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%">
                <apex:facet name="header">Fecha Caducidad</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField id="fechaC" value="{!p.Fecha_Caducidad__c}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>                 

            <apex:column style="text-align:right;" width="10%" headerClass="ct">
                <apex:facet name="header">Unidades Mínimas de Reparto</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!p.Unidad_Minima_de_Reparto__c}">
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/>
                </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>  

        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:outputpanel>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Nuevo Item" action="{!newItem}" rerender="TablaItems, showmsg" oncomplete="setFocus(this)" disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/> 
        <apex:commandButton id="grabarItem" value="Grabar Items" action="{!saveData}" oncomplete="if ({!savedOk}) {window.top.location.href='/{!id}';}" rerender="formItems, showmsg" status="loadingStatus" disabled="{!entrada.Cerrada__c}"/>
        <apex:actionStatus id="loadingStatus" startText="    Salvando..." />
        <apex:actionFunction name="actualizarProducto" reRender="formItems"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>         

  </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

<script>
    function check(){
        actualizarProducto();
        alert('{!$Component.formItem.espacioAlmacen}');
        //.pageblockItems.panelItemsEntrada.TablaItems.columnItem.espacioAlmacen
    }        
    function actualizaPosicionAlmacen(posicionAltura,id){
        document.getElementById(id).value = posicionAltura;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Carloss. Can you please let us know where are you facing issue as well as what is your question?

Comment: Thanks @RuslanVekua . I would like to send the id of the element 'MyInput' from the parent window to the child. There i will assign it a value. 

This is the result i have:

force.com/apex/Page1?id=

Comment: Can you please post a little bit of more code showing the VF page structure with the element having id myInput.

Comment: @Carloss is this code is from real code, because you can't use <apex:column alone it must be inside datatable. Also the element with id myInput is not a Apex element.

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm?search_text=Component examples on how to work the $Component global merge field type. P.S. You have to use the apex tags in order to select them through the $Component.

Comment: @SarojBera Sorry, i was trying do it fast! It is inside apex:outputpanel and an apex:pageBlockTable.

Now, im trying in an apex:element and it is not working aswell.

Thanks for ur help!!

Comment: If i try for the firs element <apex:form id="formItems"> it works! But not for an apex:outputText!

Comment: Please share your VF page otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: oK! i was trying to do it more visual but... here it goes...

Comment: $component is on the 4th column. i have an alert on a javascript to know the value aswell.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to call children of the apex:form. I tried with formItem.X but is not working for any of them.

Comment: Please read my answer and read the best practicies for accessing component IDs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm . We cannot write code for you, however you have everything to solve your problem since you just need to be aware of accessing component IDs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26655/discussion-between-ruslan-vekua-and-carloss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm) also keep in mind to reference a specific Visualforce component’s DOM ID, add a component path specifier to $Component, using dot notation

> to separate each level in the component hierarchy of the page

Try to replace you apex:outputext element with below code and take a look at the alert messages. First one has to be displayed the element ID and second one the element's inner html.

```
 <apex:outputText id="espacioAlmacen" value="some value defined by the object"/>
     <script>
       alert('{!$Component.espacioAlmacen}');//this displays an unique ID of the element
       alert(document.getElementById('{!$Component.espacioAlmacen}').innerHTML);//this displays the inner html of the element/apex:outputtext for your situation
     </script>
```